# Tapestry Error Exception Handling

Tags: exception, tapestry

I am trying to have the Exception page shown in Tapestry when my **GridDataSource** throws an exception. How do i catch a **ComponentEventException** and have Tapestry redirect to the Exception page.

Your help is much appreciated!

As per log, it reported a Caused by:

```
org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException
```

I created an object that implements ExceptionReporter, whihc Tapestry does redirect to when a exception is within the .tml page. But when an exception happens within my GridDataSource object the logs reports the exception but Tapestry does not redirect to my error page.